# How to listen mocked action with jest in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, action, jestjs

I use jest for testing my react application.

So i mocked Action for check it this toBeCalled() etc. in my test for first component.(don't listen this action)

But then i write test for another component, he listen this action and type error:

```
_edgeSnippetActions2.default.getEdgeSnippets.listen is not a function
```

So how to listen mocked action?
I just need to render this component.

```
<-action.js->

'use strict';

const Actions = jest.genMockFromModule('../loading');

Actions.set = jest.genMockFunction();

export default Actions;
```